# Saving state between activities

Tags: android

I have 2 activities named `FirstActivity.java` and `SecondActivity.java`.

When I click a button in `FirstActivity`, I call `SecondActivity`. When I return back from `SecondActivity`, based on the result, I need to skip some steps in `FirstActivity` which are performed in its `onCreate()` method.

Coming back from `SecondActivity` I used `Bundle` to put data which I gave as input to `Intent`. I accessed that data in `onCreate()` of first activity .

When I start, activity application was crashing showing as `NullPointerException` in the line where I am accessing data of 2nd activity.

The reason, I think, is when the application is launched for the first time there are no values in the `Bundle`

So, can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: If your call stack is FirstActivity->(button on screen)->SecondActivity->(hardware back button)->FirstActivity...then onCreate() is not called for the FirstActivity again.

Comment: Vuk, you are declaring a wrong assumption. While the FirstActivity is in background it may be OR may be not destroyed by the OS (it depends on current RAM state).

Comment: Yes Arhimed, I do agree. Though I would personally add all the code that 'Android_programmer_camera' wanted to be run multiple times into...mmm...say onResume() or onRestoreInstance() or something. My point being that he can not count on a low-RAM condition every time he is switching between Activities and onCreate() being called every time. But you are right, I was a bit explicit about onCreate() not ever being multi-called, that CAN happen. Cheers  :)

Answer (score 8):

You have to implement the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and save the values you would like to save into a Bundle. Implement onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) to recover the Bundle and set the data again:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /** The boolean I'll save in a bundle when a state change happens */
    private boolean mMyBoolean;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", mMyBoolean);
        // ... save more data
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mMyBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
        // ... recover more data
    }
}
```

Here you will find the usage documentation about the state handling: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Just search for thos methods in the docs :P

Comment: how to access this data in onCreate() method?

Comment: It is the argument which has been provided by onCreate():

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: how to access myBoolean in onCreate() as it is  local variable.If we make it global variable its result will value will not be as same as it is in OnRestoreInstanceState() method

Comment: the idea would be to write the content of 'getBoolean' into a variable taken from the activity. This way you recover that value. I'll edit my post :D