# State of variables inside an Android activity

Tags: android, global-variables

I have defined a global variable inside an activity, this variable changes depending on the button user has pressed.

If I go outside of my app UI and come back by holding the home button which shows the list of recent apps, then my variable keeps its state, but if I run my app again by pressing the app aicon the variable state is gone.

Is there a way to keep the state of the variable?

Comment: this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/4022933/1832000

Comment: This article can help your questions. [Click to read](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/handling-internal-variable-state-in-android-development/581)

Comment: This was in fact what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the variable's value during the [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) callback. Then you use the "icicle" parameter that is passed to and [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) to restore the value. You might be interested in reading [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Also note that Java has class variables and member variables but not global variables.

Comment: @TJ1 Thanks for accepting my answer. Note that you can also give upvotes to any questions that you find helpful. You can only accept one answer, but there is no limit on the number of upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

As what @Code-Guru says, you could use `onSaveInstanceState()` to save variable's value.

Another simple way to do is to create a static member in a static class to store the variable. The static class exists as long as the app is in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) This class is used to store and retrieve simple data.