# Limit number of button clicks

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio

I have made an app, where the user presses a button to lead onto another activity, but I only want the user to press this button 5 times in total. I tried the below code, however it doesn't stop the user pressing the button more than 5 times, so I'm guessing the app needs to somehow remember the clicks?

```
public void FoodClicks(View view){
            if(this.counter == 5){
                this.counter ++;
            }
            else {
                Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
                btn.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```

**ActivityMain.xml:**

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
android:text="@string/addmeal" />
```

Comment: How do you use FoodClicks(View) in your button? Could you post your layout xml?

Comment: Where do you use this method in fragment or in Activity?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022830/saving-state-between-activities/4022933#4022933

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak Please see XML of button above. I'm using this method within an Activity.

Comment: @NicolaBA Let's try my solution

Comment: @NicolaBA Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int clicks = 0;
        clicks++;

        if (clicks >= 5){
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("clicks", clicks);
        editor.apply();
    }
});
```

Use the `sharedPreferences` to store number of clicks, so if your button perform any action, clicks can be stored.

Comment: If the button starts a new activity each time, I doubt this will work because each time the counter will reset

Comment: @Eenvincible oh yes, button counter needs to be stored somewhere.

Comment: @Apurva yes I'm guessing that is why it isn't working for me. Any idea how I go about saving the counter?

Comment: @NicolaBA wait I try something

Comment: @Eenvincible see I used sharedPreferences to store number of clicks

Comment: @NicolaBA It took me time too to solve, btw it was first time I restricted number of clicks on button. I learned something from your question too.

Comment: You should completed this answer by showing the OP how to fetch the value from SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the increased number to your member field. Also the evaluation was not correct.

```
public void FoodClicks(View view){
        if(this.counter < 5){
            this.counter += 1;
        } else {
            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

More over, what is the view argument? The actual button? Then you can use that instead directly.

```
public void FoodClicks(View view){
        if(this.counter < 5){
            this.counter += 1;
        } else {
            ((Button) view).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed the code to yours above, however when I test the user can still click on the button more than 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

You newer call your method, add this to your xml:

```
<Button
  ...
  android:onClick = "FoodClicks"
 />
```

or implement in your `Activity` in `onCreate` method listener which will call you code:

```
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             FoodClicks(v);
         }
     });
```

And additionally you have to change your condition from

```
this.counter == 5
```

to

```
this.counter < 4
```

And remember to initialise this.counter = 0; on your `Activity`

Comment: Read the OP's question carefully.

Comment: @Apurva but when he disable button there is no many possibility to change counter any more

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak So I have set the counter to 0 = 'public int counter = 0;' and I have added the code above to my XML. There are no errors, but when I run and test on an emulator, it is still not stopping the user click on the button after 5 clicks.

Comment: @NicolaBA Did you change the condition?

Comment: @NicolaBA Change condition to `counter < 4`

Comment: @NicolaBA I tested my solution button is disabled when you click 5 times

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak Hmm, could it be something to do with the fact my button starts a new activity? The app isn't storing the counter so it might be resetting each time.

Answer (score 1):

since your using this button to open another activity so that will cause your activity to reload when you get back to it ...so the counter will be reInitialized 
one way to solve the problem is to store that counter on a save area like your Application class

Comment: I thought that might be the case. How would I go about saving the counter?

Comment: first you need to make sure that you've extended the application class as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834379/extending-android-application-class)
after that you go and place this counter that class as public static