# restricting the user to enter only 5 lines in edit text field

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I want to restrict the user to enter only 5 lines after that I should not allow the user to enter the text. I tried every thing but not getting any answers. Is there any solution please suggest me

Comment: have you tried this: `android:maxLines="5"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit number of button clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813092/limit-number-of-button-clicks)

Comment: 5 lines can mean different things on different devices if your `EditText` has not fixed width. `maxLines` could limit the number of displayed lines

Comment: better idea is to limit character inside edittext using textwatcher. And maxLines will limit the lines to be displayed not the lines to enter data.

Answer (score 0):

Use following line in your xml file for EditText control

```
android:maxLines="5"
```

Comment: this is not working I user can still enter more than 5 line but I want as after five line I need to go to next input box

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:maxLines="5"` in EditText though 5 line can be different in different devices

Comment: this is not working I user can still enter more than 5 line but I want as after five line I need to go to next input box

Comment: try to use max string size... I mean you define a maximum string size.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you....

```
 <EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxLines="5"
     android:id="@+id/ap_edit_text"/>
```

Comment: this is not working I user can still enter more than 5 line but I want as after five line I need to go to next input box